# (Excel) vba program with optional argument won't start

Tags: vba, arguments, optional-arguments

I have a program (Sub) in VBA (in Excel) that has an optional Boolean argument. The default is set to true. When I try to start the program with F8, it dings at me and does nothing. When I try to start it with F5, it brings up the program list (same as alt-F8 from within Excel itself). The program I'm trying to start is not in the list.

The relevant part of the code is just the first line:

Sub PopulateUniqueIngredientItems(Optional SortSheets As Boolean = True)

If I make argument required, it starts (but fails due to the missing argument).

Any ideas as to what am I doing wrong? Or, is it just not possible to start a Sub directly when it has a parameter?

Comment: If a Sub has parameters then you'd need to create a "stub" procedure to call it from (even when all parameters are optional and have default values): you could then run that using F5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call it without args but from another sub:

```
Sub anotherSub()
 Call PopulateUniqueIngredientItems
End Sub

Sub PopulateUniqueIngredientItems(Optional SortSheets As Boolean = True)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was afraid of. :)